# Integrals of trignometric functions

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Question is to Prove that :

$$\int_0 ^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{a+b\sin \theta}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \text{for}\  a>b>0$$

using residue theory.

What i have done so far is :

I transformed functio of $\theta$ as function of complex entity $z$ with $z=e^{i\theta}$.

Then, we have : $dz=i.e^{i\theta}.d\theta\Rightarrow dz=i.z.d\theta \Rightarrow d\theta =\frac{dz}{iz}$

$$\Rightarrow \int_0 ^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{a+b\sin \theta}=\int_{|z|\leq 1} \frac{1}{a+b.\frac{1}{2i}.(\frac{z^2-1}{z})}.\frac{dz}{iz}$$

$$\int_{|z|\leq 1} \frac{1}{a+b.\frac{1}{2i}.(\frac{z^2-1}{z})}.\frac{dz}{iz}= 2 \int_{|z|\leq 1}  \frac{1}{bz^2+(2ai)z-b} dz$$

So, now the actual problem comes :

I have to find poles for this and use residue theorem to evaluate the integrals :

$bz^2+(2ai)z-b=0 \Rightarrow z=\frac{-2ai \pm \sqrt{-4a^2+4b^2}}{2b}$. But, $a>b$ so, i would like to see this as

$\frac{-2ai \pm 2i\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{2b}=\frac{-ai \pm  i \sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}$

Now, i am not able to decide which of $\frac{-ai +  i \sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}$ and $\frac{-ai -  i \sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}$ is in $\{ z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|\leq 1\}$

I tried considering their modulus..

Please help me to understand this problem.

As this is just my third problem in "solving integrals using residue theory", I do not have much experience to tackle this problem...

Once i know what are the poles in $\{ z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|\leq 1\}$ then i know how to use residue theorem and conclude required result.

Thank You.

EDIT :

we need to consider $|\frac{-ai -  i \sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}|=\big|-i(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b})\big|=\big|\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}\big| \leq |\frac{a}{b}|+|\sqrt{(\frac{a}{b})^2-1}|$

As $a>b$, we have $\frac{a}{b}>1$ SO, I do not have specific upper bound for $\frac{a}{b}$ ..  I am confused..

even if i have $|\frac{-ai +  i \sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}|$ then also i can not see..

Comment: Page 217 Spiegel

Comment: @Samprity  Sorry, I did not get you....

Comment: What upper bound are you talking about?  You are not taking this contour out to infinity; all you are doing is computing the residue at the pole inside the unit circle.  There is no need to worry about the bounds; you have the pole, compute the residue, multiply by $i 2 \pi$, and you are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider your roots:

$$z_{\pm} = -i \left [ \frac{a}{b} \pm \sqrt{\left ( \frac{a}{b}\right)^2-1}\right]$$

Note that, when $a>b$, $a/b > 1$.  Therefore $|z_+| > 1$.  Note also that

$$|z_-| = \frac{a}{b} - \sqrt{\left ( \frac{a}{b}\right)^2-1} = \frac{1}{\frac{a}{b} + \sqrt{\left ( \frac{a}{b}\right)^2-1}} = \frac{1}{|z_+|} < 1$$

The residue at the pole $z=z_-$ is

$$\frac{2}{2 b z_-+i 2 a}  = \frac{i}{a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}-a} = \frac{-i}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$$

The value of the integral is then $2 \pi/\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$, as was to be demonstrated.

Comment: Ok. so i would take only $z_ -$ case... Thank you :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: correct.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: sorry to ask, but is there something else you need?

Comment: Just now i realized that I am still in some trouble... please see my edit for my doubt... :(